# How to visualize data as a video in R?

Tags: r, video, data-visualization

As an example, let's say we draw numbers from a normal distribution. After each time we draw a new number, we update the graph. The resulting video would show the convergence.

Are there any packages that do something like this, or maybe even more sophisticated things, like a bar chart where the bars move according to their ranking? Is R even suited for such a problem, and if not, what are the alternatives?

Comment: You might be interested in [gganimate](https://github.com/thomasp85/gganimate).

Comment: or the `animation` package